# "My seat also to go to her on my death."

Tags: sentence-structure, to-infinitive

I don't understand infinitives sometimes. Here is the sentence makes me confused.

> My seat also to go to her on my death.

Why we don't use it like or is this sentences same meaning?

*My seat also will go to her when I died.*

And can you give me more examples with this form "to + verb + to" and you choose this form?

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELL! Where did you see that sentence? Please always include a source for your quoted sentences.

Comment: Your example *My seat [**is**] also to go to her on my death* is hopelessly antiquated formal/legal phrasing, with the highlighted verb there omitted. DON'T COPY IT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second example is correct except for the tense of die (when clauses normally use present tense)

> My seat will also go to her when I die.

The meaning is slightly different.  The sentence above is a description of the future. It states a fact.

The form with the infinitive is rare (and should normally be avoided by learners) It expresses an intention or instruction. It is used in some legal documents like wills.  Normally you would either use imperatives or use "want" or similar verbs to give instructions or intentions.

> Give my seat to her when I die.
>
> I want my seat to go to her when I die.

It is worth noting that the infinitive form does not contain a finite clause, and so isn't a formal sentence of English grammar.

Comment: Thanks James 